# Prove a complex identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$

$$z=\tan\left\{\frac{1}{i}\log\left(\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}\right)^{1/2}\right\}.$$

I don't know how to start, I was thinking use the polar form... but I'm not sure if that helps... I don't know how to use $\arctan$ there's an elementary proof of this fact?

Comment: Start by $$ (\arctan(z))'= \frac{1}{1+z^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$z=\tan w=\frac{\sin w}{\cos w}=\frac{e^{iw}-e^{-iw}}{i(e^{iw}+e^{-iw})}$$
and find $w$.

Comment: I've alreday done!, thank's this suggestion was very usefull :)